# Collect "key-attribute" entries in one file and append them to key list in other file

Tags: text-processing

I got 2 files like below. The first file contains keys:

```
1
2
3
```

The second file contains keys with associated single entries:

```
1  aa
2  ab 
3  ac
2 ad
1 ae
2 af
```

I want to collect all entries belonging to the same key and print them on one line in the order defined by the first file:

```
1 aa ae 
2 ab ad af
3 ac
```

Could someone help

Answer (score 2):

Although there is certainly a possibility to do this with `miller`, an `awk`-based solution comes to mind:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if ($1 in map) map[$1]=map[$1] OFS $2; else map[$1]=$2; next}
     {print $1,map[$1]}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

This will first process the second file and gather all "values" associated with the same  "key". Then it will process the first file to output the "value" list to each key.

Answer (score 1):

And a Perl approach:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){
            chomp;
            @fields = split(/\s+/);
            push @{$values{$fields[0]}},$fields[1];
        }
        foreach $value (sort keys(%values)){
            print "$value @{$values{$value}}\n"
}' file2
```

Or, the same thing if you prefer golfing:

```
$ perl -lane 'push@{$k{$F[0]}},$F[1]}{print"$_ @{$k{$_}}"for sort keys %k' file2
1 aa ae
2 ab ad af
3 ac
```

Then, to only print values found in `file1`, you can pass it through `grep`:

```
$ perl -lane 'push@{$k{$F[0]}},$F[1]}{print"$_ @{$k{$_}}"for keys %k' file2 | 
        grep -wf file1
1 aa ae
2 ab ad af
3 ac
```